# I need a lanuage change

Tags: language-support, format

I chose a format Uzbekistan, but the system changed names of weekdays also, how do I change the whole system to eng lan, without changing its format, like(days, calendars, time format, etc)

Comment: It will help people provide you with the steps to change the language if you tell them which version of Ubuntu you are are using (Ubuntu, Kubuntu...). The settings are not the same. This site should help. https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c04948046

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do that.

One possibility is to open the `~/.profile` file for editing and add this line:

```
export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
```

After next login the weekday and month names will be in English. However, the date and time formats will be changed too (to more like what ISO prescribes). If you are not happy with that, you can test with other English locales. Possibly there is one with reasonable formats for someone who resides in Uzbekistan.